# where is the 'Editor' variable kept in git?

Tags: debian, git, editors

I cloned a repo (using fictious examples here)

```
$ git clone http://someplace.somedomain.name/resource.git
```

went to the directory

```
$ cd resource
```

and then tried to edit a file within the resource directory

```
/home/shirish/resource $ editor somefile.txt
```

Now I am not familiar with what editor is being used by git and if it something internal. I am running git 2.11.0 on Debian testing.

I did hunt around and saw this https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/ but the documentation doesn't tell me how do I search to know/see which editor it uses. Is there a way ?

Comment: `editor` is not a variable. In Debian, it's aliased to an editor command. See `which editor`, and also `namei $(which editor)`.

Comment: But if you do set a default editor for Git with `git config --global core.editor XXX`, it usually goes into `~/.gitconfig`. You can also ask Git what is the value of that variable by issuing the same command without `XXX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Debian, the `editor` command is an alternative:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

It's not managed by git.

When a git commands needs an editor (*e.g.* for a commit message), it uses the editor given by the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, or failing that, the editor specified by the `core.editor` variable. See `git-var(1)` and `git-config(1)` for details; but basically to set it up globally, run

```
git config --global core.editor emacs
```

which will store your preference in `.gitconfig` in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type editor` to see what your shell does when `editor` is entered. I don't believe it has anything to do with Git.